# Shopify option to change products per row from front-end in Dawn Theme

Tags: filter, collections, shopify, shopify-template

I need help in displaying a custom dropdown option in Shopify on the product collection template.

I need to update the number of products to be shown in a row. Users can select how many products they want to see in a row from the dropdown option. Do you have any workaround for this in Shopify or any inputs?
[image]

Comment: simply use the JS code to add and remove the specific classes to toggle the view based on selected value.

Comment: @Onkar Thanks for help. Is there any sample code snippet how to handle the ajax request on drop down change in collection template.

Comment: @Onkar Any help if you can share?